# How to pass data between top levels in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am totally new to tkinter. I am trying to pass data between two windows. There is a button on root window. button press will open a top level. There are two entry fields and a submit button in on toplevel window. user can enter two number and submit. What i am trying to achieve is, pressing submit button should close the top level and result (sum) should be shown in the root window. How to pass entry field data to root window?

```
from tkinter import *
root= Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
sum_var= StringVar()

def entry_Fn():
    level_1 = Toplevel(root)
    Label( level_1, text = "level one").pack()
    entry_1 =Entry(level_1)
    entry_1.pack()
    entry_2 =Entry(level_1)
    entry_2.pack()
    Button(level_1, text= "submit", command= submitBtn ).pack()

def submitBtn():
    val_1= entry_1.get()
    val_2= entry_2.get()
    sum_var.set(int(val_1)+ int(val_2))

Label(root, text = "Main window").pack()
Button(root, text= "To enter Data", command= entry_Fn).pack()
sum = Label(root, textvariable = sum_var)
sum.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

```
#result
val_1= entry_1.get()
NameError: name 'entry_1' is not defined

#shall I define some global variables?
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in your entry boxes as arguments to the submitBtn() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't have to declare `global`. Simply indent your `submitBtn` function inside `entry_Fn`:

```
def entry_Fn():
    level_1 = Toplevel(root)
    Label( level_1, text = "level one").pack()
    entry_1 = Entry(level_1)
    entry_1.pack()
    entry_2 = Entry(level_1)
    entry_2.pack()
    def submitBtn():
        val_1= entry_1.get()
        val_2= entry_2.get()
        sum_var.set(int(val_1)+ int(val_2))
        level_1.destroy()
    Button(level_1, text= "submit", command=submitBtn).pack()
```

But generally it is easier to make a class so you can avoid this kind of scope problems, like below:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.sum_var= StringVar()
        Label(self, text="Main window").pack()
        Button(self, text="To enter Data", command=self.entry_Fn).pack()
        sum = Label(self, textvariable=self.sum_var)
        sum.pack()

    def entry_Fn(self):
        self.level_1 = Toplevel(self)
        Label(self.level_1, text = "level one").pack()
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self.level_1)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self.level_1)
        self.entry_2.pack()
        Button(self.level_1, text="submit", command=self.submitBtn).pack()

    def submitBtn(self):
        val_1 = self.entry_1.get()
        val_2 = self.entry_2.get()
        self.sum_var.set(int(val_1)+ int(val_2))
        self.level_1.destroy()

root = GUI()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It wont't close the top level after pressing the submit button. How to close the top level automatically?

Comment: just like any widget, you can call the `destroy` method on toplevel. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can simply pass the two entries to `submitBtn()` function:

```
def submitBtn(entry_1, entry_2):
    ....
```

Then update the `command=` for the submit button inside `entry_Fn()`:

```
Button(level_1, text="submit", command=lambda: submitBtn(entry_1, enter_2)).pack()
```

Comment: but it won't close the toplevel. How to close the top level when I press the submit button? `destroy()` method?

Comment: To close the `Toplevel` window, you can either pass `level_1` to submit button as well and call `level_1.destroy()` inside the submit function, or close it in the lambda function: `command=lambda:(submitBtn(entry_1,enter_2), level_1.destroy())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `tk.TopLevel`, and use a `tk.IntVar` to transfer the data back to root:

```
import tkinter as tk


class EntryForm(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, sum_var):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Label(self, text="level one").pack()
        self.sum_var = sum_var
        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_2.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="submit", command=self.submitBtn).pack()

    def submitBtn(self):
        val_1 = self.entry_1.get()
        val_2 = self.entry_2.get()
        self.sum_var.set(int(val_1) + int(val_2))
        self.destroy()

def spawn_entry_popup():
    EntryForm(root, sum_var)

root= tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
sum_var = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(root, text = "Main window").pack()
tk.Button(root, text= "To enter Data", command=spawn_entry_popup).pack()
sum_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=sum_var)
sum_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also place your app inside a class:

```
import tkinter as tk


class EntryForm(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, sum_var):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Label(self, text="level one").pack()
        self.sum_var = sum_var
        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_2.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="submit", command=self.submitBtn).pack()

    def submitBtn(self):
        val_1 = self.entry_1.get()
        val_2 = self.entry_2.get()
        self.sum_var.set(int(val_1) + int(val_2))


class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.sum_var = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Label(self, text = "Main window").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text= "To enter Data", command=self.spawn_entry_popup).pack()
        sum_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.sum_var)
        sum_label.pack()

    def spawn_entry_popup(self):
        EntryForm(self, self.sum_var)


GUI().mainloop()
```

Comment: but how to close the top level window automatically when i am pressing the submit button?

Comment: sorry, I missed that part - you simply destroy the `Toplevel` after having updated `self. sum_var` - I edited the code.